# What would be some noticeable differences on tiny human beings?

Tags: internal-consistency, humanoid, genetic-engineering

Let's say a very advanced alien race makes tiny human beings just for fun. Of course they wouldn't be just shrunken normal humans because they'd just die, the alien race made the necessary changes for the Tiny Humans™ to be able to live.

They would have a shorter lifespan than normal humans and would also would be about 13cm/5ish inches tall.

Their body temperature would probably be higher and they probably would eat more compared to humans who would just be tiny with no necessary changes for actually living. I am not a member of this alien race trying desperately to finish my school project, meaning that I don't know much about the subject. What would be some noticeable differences between humans and Tiny Humans™?

Comment: They'd be unintelligent due to lack of brain.

Comment: It's alien science, they are as smart as humans.

Comment: If "it's alien science" is a valid counterargument to any logical inference, then that suggests there is no answer.  You merely need to tabulate a list of which alien science things happen, and then worry about the physics and biology for everything else.

Comment: That could work but I want something loosely grounded in science. How their body and brain works being the size they are? That doesn't need awnsering in the context of the story. The things I'm looking for are differences that they would display that would be comparable to other small animals. Sorry if my english is not good, it's not my main language.

Comment: You are asking us to compile a list. This is one of those cases clearly listed as "what questions should I avoid asking?" in the [help]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking an open-ended "what if" sort of thing.

Comment: From your description of what differences you already expect, I would actually think purely shrunken humans would be more likely to survive. I think this is a situation where you are already using so much handwavium, explaining other parts more in depth would just be frustrating. As a reader I would be upset if I read through an in depth description of alien biology, and then get to "because Alien Science"...

Comment: ***'Of course they wouldn't be just shrunken normal humans because they'd just die'*** : really? seems the mice haven't heard yet, nobody tell them, as long as they don't know they should be OK ~  So why do you think miniature humans are any more likely to die than a mouse? ~ there really is no logic or reason for that supposition, I'll go further, the statement that 'miniature humans would die' is wrong.

Comment: The [Etruscan shrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etruscan_shrew) is 4 cm long (you only want 5 cm) ~ [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3YZXnVaXBA&vl=en) looks fine to me, not dead at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smaller vocal cords would make higher pitched voices.  Smaller cochlea would resonate to higher frequency sound.  Smaller eyes would require the eye lens to bend more to focus light in a shorter distance.  Smaller ratio of mass to lung surface area would mean they would hyperventilate if they didn't breathe much more slowly, which could make speech slower.  In proportion to their weight, they'd be able to lift more.  In proportion to their height they could fall greater distances safely.